# Probability based on euclidean distance

Tags: probability, graph-algorithm, genetic-algorithm, euclidean-distance

First of all sorry for the ambiguous title.

I am working on a genetic algorithm for Multiple Depot Vehicle Routing Problem.
I am creating candidate solution based on the distances from customers to depots. I have created a method that creates a probability for each depot of serving each customer. Pseudocode below:

```
for each customer

    for each depot
        calculate euclidean distance between customer and depot

    get the maximum distance

    for each depot
        totalDistance = totalDistance + (maximumDistance - currentDepotDistance)

    for each depot 
        depotProbability = (maximumDistance - currentDepotDistance) / totalDistance
```

The results are the following:

[image]

While this formula works I would like to be able to somehow increase or decrease the probabilities in order to find an appropriate ratio. I would like to be able to move from the point where the closest depot is always chosen to the point where depots are randomly assigned.

**EDIT**
Results after implementing the algorithm in the accepted answer:

T=0.1 Closest depot to every customer
[image]

T=20 Other routes taken into account

[image]

Comment: what is your target metric?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't understand your question

Comment: what is it that you're trying to optimize?

Comment: I am trying to find a balance between random assignment and strict assignment. The current method inclines too the random assignment. I have 32 test cases with different patterns so I would like to be able to change the probabilities.

Comment: Balance measured by what? Total distance traveled? Minimum amount of angular change? Minimum path intersections?

Comment: The point of the Vehicle Routing Problem is too reduce the cost. The idea of the genetic algorithm is to start with an initial population (in our case a number of possible solutions). So at one end all the candidate solutions are the same (the closest depot for the customer) and at the other end is random assignment (not cost efficient). I am trying to find a balance between the two ends to minimize the total distance showed in the picture.

Comment: So "cost" is the total distance traveled, right?

Comment: To me this looks quite a bit like an application for Viterbi, if you try to think of the set of possible links as stages in a Trellis graph, but that's probably not even leading to a solution in the general case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try something like [softmax action selection](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/2/node4.html):

[image]

Where `d` is each depot and τ is the "temperature" parameter. When τ → 0, your selection turns into greedy selection (always the smallest distance). When τ → ∞, your selection becomes random.

Comment: is `d` a depot? So the denominator would be the sum of  ` e to the power each distance over T` ?

Comment: Exactly. Just to make sure: it is negative distance, not distance.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works great. I also added the results to the question.